# Installing g++ = 7.5.0 with support for Cilk Plus

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, g++, cilk

I want to use https://github.com/yushangdi/parChain however I can't fullfil requirement:

```
Compiler:

g++ = 7.5.0 with support for Cilk Plus
```

I have a problem with installing GCC with Cilk. I try to follow some tutorials from the websites but any of them doesn't work correctly. Unfortunately, the Cilk project was transformed into Intel's project many documentation URLs don't work anymore. I got following error after run `$./pc_exp.sh`

```
In file included from sequence.h:27:0,
                 from framework.C:1:
parallel.h:25:10: fatal error: cilk/cilk.h: Not found
 #include <cilk/cilk.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

```
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 7.5.0-6ubuntu2' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-7 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-6ubuntu2) 
$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 7.5.0-6ubuntu2' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-7 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-6ubuntu2)
```

I need to run this on both: Ubuntu 20.04 and Centos 7. I'm not Linux/c++ experienced user. Can you help me with some tutorials?

Comment: does this help: http://cilkplus.github.io/#try?

Comment: ```sanitizer_platform_limits_posix.cc:164:10: fatal error: sys/ustat.h: no such file or directory
 #include <sys/ustat.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.``` This the error which I get when I follow instructions from this url.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you consider OpenCilk, an active open source project that picks up where Cilk Plus left off. OpenCilk 2.0 was released just a couple weeks ago, and it definitely supports Ubuntu 20.04. (Not sure about Centos.) Please see https://www.opencilk.org for tutorials on programming with Cilk (which is based on LLVM btw).